# What is the definition of a string in Bash?

Tags: bash, debian, terminal

What is the definition of a string in Bash?

Bash use the term "string" several places in its documentation, e.g. to document the `=~` operator used for regular expression matching:

> An additional binary operator, =~, is available, with the same precedence as == and !=.  When it is used, the **string** to the right of the operator is considered a POSIX extended regular expression and matched  accordingly  (as  in  regex(3)).

In the section `DEFINITIONS`, I don't see any definition of strings:

```
DEFINITIONS
       The following definitions are used throughout the rest of this document.
       blank  A space or tab.
       word   A sequence of characters considered as a single unit by the shell.  Also known as a token.
       name   A word consisting only of alphanumeric characters and underscores, and beginning with an alphabetic character or an underscore.  Also referred to as an identifier.
       metacharacter
              A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
              |  & ; ( ) < > space tab newline
       control operator
              A token that performs a control function.  It is one of the following symbols:
              || & && ; ;; ;& ;;& ( ) | |& <newline>
```

So, what exactly are strings in Bash? May they contain whitespace or characters in the `IFS` environment variable?

NB: I know strings are normally defined as a series of symbols in an alphabet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bash manual doesn’t define strings, but [it does say that](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/What-is-Bash_003f.html#What-is-Bash_003f)

> It is intended to be a conformant implementation of the IEEE POSIX Shell and Tools portion of the IEEE POSIX specification (IEEE Standard 1003.1).

so one can assume that [the POSIX definition of strings](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html#tag_03_375) applies:

> A contiguous sequence of bytes terminated by and including the first null byte.

Comment: Thanks you. So, strings like those provided for `=~` may by definition contain any character except zero-byte. But I can’t quote the entire string to preserve spaces, otherwise Bash do word splitting, since quoting the string means to interprete it as a fixed string (not a regex). Can I get around it by writing something like: `a(“ “|b)c” “d+`? Will Bash do word splitting here or read it as a one contiguous string, with the `” “` being interpreted as fixed spaces? Why?

Comment: You can escape spaces with backslashes: `a(\ |b)c\ d+`. Quoting  spaces works too, Bash won’t split words; I don’t have a reference off-hand.

Comment: But wouldn’t my example work too? Sorry, I can’t test it right now, since I’m in transport, but will do so later.

Comment: Yes, like I said, quoting spaces works too, so your example works.